# Why does 2px border render taller than 2px height in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to create a line in 2 different ways. One is with a div with a height of 2px and a background (red). The other is with a div that has a 2px top border (blue). Here's the test code:

```css
.line {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50px;
}

.height-line {
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}

.border-line {
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="line height-line"></div>
<div class="line border-line"></div>
```

These ***should*** appear the same, but in Chrome, you can see that the left div appears to be 1px thicker than the right div. And in Firefox, as you slowly change the height of the browser window, you can see the height fluctuating between 3px and 2px (you'll actually need to view the [equivalent jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L1tq8cny/4/) to see this behavior in Firefox - I think b/c of the way the display is embedded in the stackoverflow snippet, it doesn't happen).

**NOTE:** My zoom is correctly set to 100%, and I've verified the same behavior in another developer's browser. I'm on Windows 7, using Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: At least in the snippet, and viewed in Chrome they appear the same to me. (Not the downvote, since I assume something must be going on.)

Comment: They look the same to me in both Chrome and Firefox, too.

Comment: They appear the same to me as well (Chrome) unless I zoom in or out.  Then they appear to differ.

Comment: Inspeting with chrome i get 50x2 in .test1 and 50x1.6 in .test2

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, can you attach a screenshot

Comment: Possibly aliasing

Comment: Maybe is related to the screen, as some people can see it and some can't

Comment: Unfortunately people often confuse bad questions with well described but not 100% reproducable questions... What OS are you running? I also cannot reproduce this issue on either browser on Win7.

Comment: @Christoph - I'm on Windows 7 (added to question).

Comment: But what have you search about this ? Aside ... don't complain about votes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix zoom issues with Google Chrome and 1px Width/Height DIVs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740182/how-to-fix-zoom-issues-with-google-chrome-and-1px-width-height-divs)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394545/what-could-make-firefox-render-an-incorrect-border-width ... For reference to try this

Comment: @Rob - as noted in the question, I made sure that my zoom is 100% on all browsers, but I'm still experiencing the issue.

Comment: Your browser zoom is 100% but what about your display scale factor? That screenshot suggests it might be the latter that's the issue.

Comment: Can you please set different colours for background and border so you can distinguish them?

Comment: @jbyrd Giving the actual value of `devicePixelRatio` will be clearer than either zoom level or display scale.

Comment: @JoshLee - good call - it was 1.25. After changing my windows display value from the default Medium (125%) to Smaller (100%), devicePixelRatio becomes 1, and the issue goes away.

Comment: @BoltClock - yes, that was exactly the issue. Funny that the default display scale (Medium) is 125% and causes the issue. When I changed it to Smaller (100%), the problem is gone.

Comment: Curiously enough, specifying the `border-width` to medium makes it appear normal as well. https://jsfiddle.net/t2yy6629/

Comment: Fixed, to some extent, in Chrome 58. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/934becac5daa91ea979fb66e4ae21761ca11ebc9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a browser bug, and is affected by Windows' display scale factor. The default display scale factor is 125%. Open an explorer window and go to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display", then change the Display to "Smaller - 100%", and restart your computer:

[image]

The issue should then be gone.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, because a great many users are going to be at 125%, and you cannot ask them to change this.

Comment: I added that this may be a browser bug.